# How to rename filenames using string values from hash?

Tags: ruby

I've got a directory with files:

```
folder/
  -spider.rb
  -elephant.rb
  -monkey.rb
```

I also have hash, containing such pairs

```
rename_filenames = 
{ "spider" => "bear",
  "elephant" => "rat",
  "monkey" => "tiger" }
```

How can I rename files with values from the hash?

```
folder/
  -bear.rb
  -rat.rb
  -tiger.rb
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply iterate over the hash and rename accordingly:

```
rename_filenames.each do |old_name, new_name|
  File.rename("folder/#{old_name}.rb", "folder/#{new_name}.rb")
end
```

Comment: The answer is good and actually perfectly solves the problem. However, I'm afraid what if filenames could contain other symbols apart from full match? In this case, I'd have to use completely different approach.

Comment: `what is filenames contain other symboms`... What are you talking about? Globs? Regex? ...?

Comment: Imagine if files were named `5643_spider.rb, 3232_elephant.rb` etc.

Comment: @AlexanderShmatko In that case you need to iterate over each file in the directories and make pattern matching.

Comment: Agree, you're right. But how would I fetch the keys from hash to make pattern matching? `Dir.glob('folder', '**.rb') { |f| f.match( ? ) }`

Comment: @AlexanderShmatko I'm by no means a ruby linguist. But you would need to iterate over all files in a directory, and then iterate over the hash for each file.

Comment: Thank you, though! Much appreciated :)